# Capturar query string no WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, aplicação-web

Estou tentando capturar a query string `paged` na página principal para chamar um componente e carregar os dados. Porém, o retorno dela é sempre `0`.

Quando utilizo este componente em outras páginas, funciona normalmente.

**Estrutura da URL com a Query String**

> http://minha_url.com.br/estilo/page/2/

**Componente capturando a query string**

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

**Página principal chamando o componente**

```
<section class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9 order-1 order-lg-2">
    <h2 class="sr-only">Posts recentes</h2>
    <?php get_template_part('components/content', 'posts'); ?>
</section>
```

**Retorno do `get_query_var('paged')` dentro da página principal**

> 0

Não costumo utilizar WordPress mas creio que não seja um erro complexo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que 0 seja o valor real de paged mesmo. Você pode printar a global $wp_query->query_vars que o valor na página inicial deverá ser de fato 0.

Fiz isso com meu WordPress local na página inicial e o retorno foi o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [category_name] => 
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 
    [tag_id] => 
    [author] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [title] => 
    [fields] => 
    [menu_order] => 
    [embed] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_name__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [post_type] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 50
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => DESC
)
```

O código que utilizei foi este:

```
global $wp_query;
print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso teria que retornar o valor que está na URL, não é?

Comment: Então, o valor antes de estar na URL está na query. Mas dependendo de como você montou sua query, a paginação pode se comportar como numa página estática. Nesse caso teria que pegar o valor de 'page' ao invés de 'paged'. Exemplo: 


`$page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`